# How can I remove the values of a column of a data set that contain specific number of digits in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set that looks like this :

```
vec = c(989, 987, 145, 315, 8449, 9999999999000)
char = c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
df2 = tibble(vec,char);df2
# A tibble: 6 × 2
            vec char 
          <dbl> <chr>
1           989 a    
2           987 b    
3           145 c    
4           315 d    
5          8449 e    
6 9999999999000 f
```

I want to remove the values from the column vector that contains more than or equal to 5 digits. Ideally I want to look like this :

```
1           989 a    
2           987 b    
3           145 c    
4           315 d    
5          8449 e
```

How can I do this in R using dplyr ?

Any help ?

Comment: Can values be floating point? Count before decimal point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nchar` in `base R`

```
subset(df2, nchar(vec) <6)
```

Or `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df2, nchar(vec) <6)
# A tibble: 5 × 2
    vec char 
  <dbl> <chr>
1   989 a    
2   987 b    
3   145 c    
4   315 d    
5  8449 e
```

If there are decimals, convert to integer and count

```
filter(df2, nchar(as.integer(vec)) < 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% filter(!str_count(vec, '\\d{5,}') == 1)

# A tibble: 5 × 2
    vec char 
  <dbl> <chr>
1   989 a    
2   987 b    
3   145 c    
4   315 d    
5  8449 e
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check

```r
tibble(vec,char) %>% filter(nchar(vec)<=4)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 2
    vec char 
  <dbl> <chr>
1   989 a    
2   987 b    
3   145 c    
4   315 d    
5  8449 e
```